# How do I convert a JSON array with a string value into a string

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am using set-variable to save one field from the payload into a variable. I would like to save this variable as a string, but it ends up as a JSON array. I then need to concatenate this value with a value from my local configuration file.

I need to either save the payload field as a string or convert the array into a string during concatenation. However, I can't seem to do either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a misunderstanding on my part. The incoming payload was an array so this field was an array. I wrapped it in a foreach and everything worked.